# vue img will not render object.value from data()

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs2, rendering

sorry if I'm just new to vue and bugging myself up. I'm trying to render an img with a src that comes from an object property which comes from an array I return from data()

I'm not getting any errors but I'm not seeing any icon appear, I am using other images from the same directory with no problems so I'm assuming my syntax is just wrong I have validated the img src is correct I don't see a different way to do this from googling around so I'm hoping someone has some insight for me :)

I've found that I do get an error if I use

```
v-bind:src="getImage(imagePath)"
```

If I do this is looks like vue looks for the file but returns an error in the console that it cannot find the item, I used the file elsewhere outside the for loop and it worked fine :/

my console also shows the img src correctly in the source code on render
[image]

template

```
 <!-- active agencies -->
<b-tab title="Active" active><b-card-text>
  <ul class="pendingAgencyList">
    <li v-for="agent in pendingAgency" :key="agent.Status">       
      <div v-if="agent.Status == 'active'" class="pendingAgencyItem">
        <img :src="agent.Icon" :key="agent.Status" height="30px" width="30px"/> //ADDING IMAGE HERE
        <small>Name</small>
        <p>{{ agent.Name }}</p>
      </div>
      <div v-if="agent.Status == 'active'" class="pendingAgencyItem">
        <small>Contact</small>
        <p>{{agent.Contact}}</p>
      </div>
      <p v-if="agent.Status == 'active'" >{{agent.Status}}</p>                
    </li>
  </ul>
</b-card-text></b-tab>
```

for reference here is a sample of  my data

```
data() {
      return {
        pendingAgency:[
          {
            Icon: '../assets/agency_logo-2.png',
            Name: "Moony Fox",
            Contact: "345-235-7685",
            Status: "pending"
          },
          {
            Icon: '../assets/agency_logo-5.png',
            Name: "Bofy Fox",
            Contact: "345-235-7685",
            Status: "Rejected"
          },
          {
            Icon: '../assets/agency_logo-3.png',
            Name: "Felony Mo",
            Contact: "345-235-7685",
            Status: "red"
          }        
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can try to set data like:

```
{
  Icon: 'agency_logo-3',
   ...
 }
```

then create method:

```
methods: {
  getImage(img) {
     return require('../assets/' + img+ '.png';
  }
}
```

then in template call method:

```
<img :src="getImage(agent.Icon)" :key="agent.Status" height="30px" width="30px"/>
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, doesn't seem to return anything

Comment: there are no errors which makes me thing the source is just wrong somehow? but the path works fine when I manually render an element outside of the v-for loop

Comment: I have also tried using v-bind but I get the same result ```<img v-bind:src="agent.Icon" :key="agent.Status" height="40px" width="40px"/>```

Comment: `v-bind:src` is the same as `:src` , did you try to set path in data like `@/assets/agency_logo-5.png`?

Comment: I did try to set the path, didn't seem to make a difference, maybe its some weird css reason because the actual image path shows in the source code on the page I have edited my question with the info

Comment: i just tried your code and it works, though without b-tab, and with code from my answer, so it can be related to css

Comment: interesting, I tried loading the same images in a different div, not using any bootstrap or custom component but I'm getting the same issue, I removed any css on my components affecting the images

Comment: Sorry mate,like i told you it works fine at my copy of your component, with settings like in my answer .(

Comment: hmm so I went back and double checked and your code did fix it for me :) so I wanted to say thanks a bunch! interested to know why supplying the path in various parts solves the issue.... perhaps component render timing has something to do with it?